# Is It Possible to Get the Currently Executing Delegate (not MethodBase/MethodInfo) by 3rd Party Library?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have been wracking my brain over this, but I cannot find an answer to it.

I am aware of `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` but I am curious if there is an equivalent to get the currently executing `Delegate` (if there is one executing, that is).

Is this possible, by chance? (**Edit**: This appears conclusively to not be possible via core .NET, so I am wondering if there is a 3rd party library that might do this.)

For reference, I would like to do the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var target = new Inner();

    var reference = new Action( target.HelloWorld ); // Creates a System.Delegate reference.
    reference();
}

class Inner
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(); // Current method.
        var current = DelegateContext.GetCurrentDelegate(); // <==== Magic happens here. Gets "reference" from above.
    }
}
```

**Why?** As for why I want to do this: For each reference I want to associate some data specific to that Delegate (sort of like ambient data that is not an explicit passed in variable).  When the Delegate executes, I then retrieve that data (by way of `ConditionalWeakTable` or equivalent lookup) and use it within the delegate.

Comment: Can you illustrate the problem through an example?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. A delegate is just a pointer to a method. At the time it's executing, there's no difference between a method and a delegate.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver technically a delegate is a method coupled with a target object.  I have heard of it described as a tuple in this regard.

Comment: Fair point. In this regard I'm not sure whether that's a practical difference for this scenario. Are you really just looking for an instance to the object where the current method is defined?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 good point.  Silly me, I should have known better. :)  Edited and added.

Comment: I imagine you would have to analyze the stack for a delegate object that points to the currently executing method and object. I know how to do this in WinDbg (!dso) but have never tried that from within running .Net code.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver correct.  I am looking for the actual reference to the currently executing delegate, if there is one.  I have provided sample pseudo code to help out.

Comment: @Christoph indeed.  I can get an object reference, the MethodInfo reference, but not the Delegate, unless I do a bunch of magic, and before I do so I wanted to see if that magic is already made. :)

Comment: @Mike-EEE I don't think you can get the `reference`, other than hard-coding a local variable look up in the stack frame. Since invoking `reference` is not much different than invoking the delegate directly. The closest you can get is the caller, be `Main()` in this case. Is that what you want instead?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the stack is referencing `MethodInfo` objects and not `Delegate` objects.

Comment: @Mike-EEE The `Delegate` won't even be present on the stacks. The stack will look like this : (from top to bottom) at `Inner.HelloWorld`, at `???Application.Main()`.

Comment: The delegate doesn't execute. The method/code pointed to by the delegate is what executes. So no, what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: @sstan The method/code (method body) is indeed ultimately what executes, but if a Delegate is invoked, this is the causing factor to initiate that workflow, and what I am interested in.  You are indeed correct that is not possible via core .NET, but I am wondering if this is possible via a 3rd party library of some sort.  Updated question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't actually make sense at execution time. The delegate is just a pointer to something so you can execute it later.

It's not possible for you to get the *same* reference which is used above - that's just a local variable which isn't accessible to you. The best you can do (which in practical terms is the same thing) is get the current object instance and create a new `Action` using [Delegate.CreateDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx).

Comment: This will create a new reference altogether.  I am wanting to get the exact reference of the created delegate signified by `var reference` in my example above.  And are you **100%** certain this is not possible?  Maybe a library somewhere might have this solved, perhaps?

Comment: What is the problem of having a 'different' instance of the delegate?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen For each reference I want to associate some data specific to the Delegate.  When the Delegate executes, I then get that data.  I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: When comparing Delegates; it compares the Target object and the MethodInfo, not the instance itself. So a new reference to the same target/methodinfo is considered equal.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen That is incorrect.  It is a new reference altogether.  An object.ReferenceEquals check returns false.

Comment: You might read my comment again, it **doesn't** say that those delegates are equal. Considered equal. But if you compare them, it returns true. `Object.Equals()`. How do you store the extra information? Dictionary?

Comment: I see @JeroenvanLangen yes... I am looking for reference equality as I am using a ConditionalWeakTable so that it is based on reference, not equality (for WeakReference/memory reasons).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this isn't possible. Your actual delegate reference is a local variable of the Main method. It is guaranteed by the rules of the language not to be available from outside that method.

Comment: It sounds like you're just using the Delegate reference as a unique identifier, which isn't reliable. Why not just create another unique identifier (like a GUID) and pass it as a method parameter to your HelloWorld method? Then that identifier can be used to look up the ambient data you need.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I am wanting to do this in a general, abstract way so that I can do this with any Delegate without having to change their signatures.  I can certainly store the reference to the Delegate (in a Dictionary defined in Main's parent class, for instance), so it will be available outside that method.  The question is how to access it while the Delegate is executing.

Comment: You still can't. Let's say you store the Delegate in a Dictionary, for example. You still have a lot of items in the dictionary, so you have to be able to pass a unique identifier to know *which* delegate to get. You're still stuck passing that identifier.

Comment: Exactly my problem @TimCopenhaver and why my brain is fried over this. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114640/discussion-between-mike-eee-and-tim-copenhaver).

Comment: Well looks like I struck out on this.  Thank you for your patience and questions, everyone.  I didn't do a good job initially with presenting the information, and left more questions than answers in my approach.  I will do better going forward in being more thorough with my questions. Btw @JeroenvanLangen I have an open question for you in chat.  Thanks again everyone!